# Запуск mongos выдает ошибку

Tags: mongodb

При запуске mongos
`mongos --configdb localhost:47040` выдает ошибку: BadValue: configdb supports only replica set connection string
try 'mongos --help' for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создадим 4 пустых директории:
   `mkdir sh1, sh2, conf1, conf2`
2. Поднимаем 2 сервера mongod:
   `mongod.exe --shardsvr --dbpath C:\data\sh1 --bind_ip localhost --port 27000`

`mongod.exe --shardsvr --dbpath C:\data\sh2 --bind_ip localhost --port 27001`
3.  Поднимем 2 сервера конфигурации:
`mongod.exe --configsvr --replSet configrs  --dbpath C:\data\conf1  --bind_ip localhost --port 27002`

`mongod.exe --configsvr --replSet configrs  --dbpath C:\data\conf2 --bind_ip localhost --port 27003`

4. Подключимся к одному серверу конфигурации:
   `mongo.exe localhost:27002`
5. Зададим настройку реплики
   `rs.initiate( { _id: "configrs", members: [ { _id : 0, host : "localhost:27002" }, { _id : 1, host : "localhost:27003" } ] } )`
6. Поднимем сервер коммутатор mongos:
   `mongos.exe --configdb configrs/localhost:27002 --bind_ip localhost --port 27004`
7. Подключаемся к серверу коммутатору:
   `mongo.exe localhost:27004`
8. Прописываем шарды:
   `sh.addShard("localhost:27000")`
   `sh.addShard("localhost:27001")`
9. Для проверки введём команду:
   `db.printShardingStatus()`